# bootstrap is not defined when trying to use Bootstrap 5 with Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, npm, bootstrap-5, vite

This is a commom question, but none of solutions has worked so far. I'm using Laravel 10 with Vite, installed Bootstrap with NPM and the configuration was ok to use bootstrap css and bootstrap icons, but I can't load boostrap js, which is necessary to make it work modals, toasts, pop-ups, etc.

vite.config.js:

```
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: ['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '~bootstrap': path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/bootstrap"),
            '~bootstrap-icons': path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/bootstrap-icons/font")
        }
    }
});
```

resources/js/app.js

```
import * as bootstrap from 'bootstrap';
```

Importing files in the main blade.php layout (where all other pages extend):

```
...
@vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])
...
```

And the blade.php page where the error occurs (bootstrap is not defined)

```
...
<script>
    window.onload = () => {
        const toastLiveExample = document.querySelector("#liveToast")
        const toast = new bootstrap.Toast(toastLiveExample)
        toast.show()
    }
</script>
...
```

Comment: Can you specify exact error message from terminal or from browser console?

Comment: @Tpojka Uncaught ReferenceError: bootstrap is not defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `app.js` file. You can define `window.bootstrap = bootstrap` so that you can use it in your blade.

```js
import * as bootstrap from 'bootstrap';
window.bootstrap = bootstrap;
```